# Database design question (extra fields vs extra table)

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am designing a (relational) database schema and wanted to inquire which of the following would be the most appropriate design.

**Scenario:**

**Table ProductProperties: 60 fields (foreign key reference to Users table via field CreatedBy)**

**Table Users : 5 fields**

The application also allows users to create **basic and advanced filters**. These filters are the same as the properties in ProductProperties table. Basic filter uses 10 fields, while an advanced filter is composed of all 60.

Now I can either:

**1) Add three fields to Table ProductProperties** namely, FilterName, IsAdvancedFilter, IsFilter (resulting in lots of null values for records which are actual products but not filters)

Or,

**2) Create a Filters table** which would be a near replica of the ProductProperties table resulting in two big very similar tables

Which would be the better design ?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you use ProductProperties? Do we have any product table, which has foreign key of ProductProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Which would be the better design ?*

Well, not "design", but choice of two proposals.  Definitely (2)

As far as design is concerned, ProductProperties with 60 fields, null values, and very large, is not normalised.  So the first thing to do if you want design or a database, is normalise the beast.

- Right now, you are handling flat files which are sitting in a container labelled "database", and you can use a few (certainly not most) SQL functions on it.

Then you will have design.  And several smaller tables, which are easier to deal with, and allow more relational capability.  Then when you add filters, you will be adding a few smaller tables, as appropriate, not adding three columns to a single unwieldy table, or making a copy of it.

Second, and separate to the above, I do not understand how or why (2) the Filter table, would be a near replica of Product Properties, can you please explain.

Comment: The filter table is a near replica of the product properties table because a the application allows filtering by product properties and Users can store the filters they create. A basic filter uses only 5 properties, while an advanced filter uses all properties.

Comment: Also the product properties table can be normalized but that will vastly increase the number of joins.

Comment: @fjxx. 1) Ok, but you have a separate Product table. Are you using freeware (non-SQL) like My"SQL") 2) So what is the fear of increasing the number of joins ?  That is the nature of Relational Databases. 3) If you post your DDL (tables and Indices), and identify all ProductTypes & Properties of each, I will fix your entire problem, including performance.

Answer (score 1):

The better design is always to have different "things" in different tables.  If a filter is truly different from a product, mixing them together will create many headaches when trying to deal with them.  Keeping them separate eliminates those headaches.

As for the common columns: tables are not classes, it's ok if some of them have columns in common.

Final thought.  When you add a column to one, you will have to add it to another.  This is trivial compared to the headaches you get when unlike things are mixed into the same table just because they have values in common.